# Converting an integer to 0x equivalent (Hex)

Tags: c, bcd

I have an integer input of 1991. How do I convert the input to 0x1991 instead of 7C7? I already wrote the code to convert the hex to decimal(the answer will be 6545)

```
int ui = 0x202;
int BCD(int value) //Converting 0xhex to decimal 
{
    int result = 0;
    result <<= 4;
    result |= ui % 10;
    ui /= 10;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [`strtol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc.aspx)?

Comment: If @WeatherVane's comment doesn't help you, please include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the hint, what exactly you do expect from the code.

Comment: To convert from decimal to BCD, start with zero result and multiplier 1. In a loop, divide the decimal value by ten, but take the remainder first. Multiply the remainder with the multiplier, and add to result. Multiply multiplier by 16. Repeat loop as long as the decimal value is greater than zero. To convert from BCD to decimal, you do the same, except you divide the BCD value by 16, and multiply the multiplier by 10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408361/unsigned-integer-to-bcd-conversion

Comment: @M.M your link helps :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

```
const int input = 1991;
int i = input;
int f = 1;
int result = 0x0;
while( i > 0 )
{
    int d = i % 10;
    result += d * f;
    f *= 16; 
    i /= 10;
}

printf("0x%x", result ); // 0x1991
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ui` as the input and storing the result in `result`, but then returning `value`; you should be using `value` as the input and returning `result`.

Comment: The code is meant to convert 0x based numbers, For example, BCD(0x1991) which will give you the answer of 6545 . However, I have no clue how to convert 1991 to 0x1991

Comment: @xTiraMissU: That's not what you asked, even if it is what you meant to ask.  Regardless, what I wrote still applies.

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed that :) Thank you for correcting my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Build a string with the 0x prefix, then scan that.

```
int var, value = 1991;
char tmp[100];
sprintf(tmp, "0x%d", value);
if (sscanf(tmp, "%i", &var) != 1) /* error */;
printf("%d ==> %s ==> %d\n", value, tmp, var);
```